# Issue trying to build FFmpeg for ARM with librtmp support

Tags: arm, rtmp

I am trying to compile librtmp so I can build FFmpeg with RTMP support for ARM processor.

I already have the toolchain, and solo build of FFmpeg was also successful, and testing from inside the ARM processor was success as well.

My understanding:

```
- Ffmpeg
--  Librtmp
--- Openssl
--- zlib
```

This hierarchy is required to build FFmepg.

So far I have built  openssl for ARM, and zlib for ARM, and, I can see it is located in right ARM output folder.

Prerequisites:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/lib/
export CCPREFIX="/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/bin/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-"
export CFLAGS="-I/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/lib/"
```

1-      Steps to build zlib:

```
export CC=arm-linux-gcc
./configure --prefix=/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr
make
make install
```

2-      Steps to build openssl:

```
export cross=arm-linux-
./Configure dist --prefix=/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr
make CC="${cross}gcc" AR="${cross}ar r" RANLIB="${cross}ranlib"
make install
```

3-      Steps to build librtmp:

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux- INC=-I/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/include LIB=-L/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/lib
```

above 1,2 steps are successful, with 3rd, I get this:

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux- INC=-I/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/include LIB=-L/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/lib
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/Downloads/ip_code/rtmpdump/librtmp'
arm-linux-gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,librtmp.so.1  -o librtmp.so.1 rtmp.o log.o amf.o hashswf.o parseurl.o  -lssl -lcrypto -lz
/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/4.4.0/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/4.4.0/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/4.4.0/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:92: recipe for target 'librtmp.so.1' failed
make[1]: *** [librtmp.so.1] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Downloads/ip_code/rtmpdump/librtmp'
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'librtmp/librtmp.a' failed
make: *** [librtmp/librtmp.a] Error 2
```

but in the output folder I can see the right files are there:

```
[user@localhost rtmpdump]$ cd /opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr/lib
[user@localhost lib]$ ls
bin                  libavcodec.a      libgmp.so.10.0.2  libz.so
certs                libavdevice.a     libiberty.a       libz.so.1
engines              libavfilter.a     libmpfr.la        libz.so.1.2.11
gcc                  libavformat.a     libmpfr.so        man
include              libavutil.a       libmpfr.so.4      misc
ldscripts            libcrypto.a       libmpfr.so.4.0.1  openssl.cnf
lib                  libfakeroot-0.so  libpostproc.a     pkgconfig
libaacplus.a         libfakeroot.la    libssl.a          private
libaacplus.la        libfakeroot.so    libswresample.a   share
libaacplus.so        libgmp.la         libswscale.a
libaacplus.so.2      libgmp.so         libx264.a
libaacplus.so.2.0.2  libgmp.so.10      libz.a
[user@localhost lib]$
```

Any idea how to compile?

Thanks

Comment: The libraries are `.a`, but you have `-shared` on the command line.  Do you have shared ARM SSL `.so` files available on the build machine?

Comment: I do not see it there. Just to compile it, I called Configure with this option: ./Configure dist --prefix=/opt/toolchain_gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/usr, followed by make and make install. Even after doing this I do not see the files in the ARM /opt/..../lib folder. And I tried finding -shared option in MAKEFILE of rtmpdump, but there is no mention of this there. I wonder what is forcing rtmpdump/librtmp to build it with -shared option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for info: the rtmpdump is apparently a requirement for some other OS... I compiled FFmpeg without rtmpdump/librtmp yesterday, and in the 'enabled protocols' at time of ./configure , I could see RTMP/RTMPS etc. as well...

Very surprised, I ran the compiled FFmpeg on the targetted ARM device, and it runs without any issue: I guess support was already there inside ffmpeg (for ARM), while I was wrestling with rtmpdump.

```
Enabled protocols:
async              httpproxy          rtmpte
cache              https              rtmpts
concat             icecast            rtp
crypto             md5                srtp
data               mmsh               subfile
ffrtmpcrypt        mmst               tcp
ffrtmphttp         pipe               tee
file               prompeg            tls_openssl
ftp                rtmp               udp
gopher             rtmpe              udplite
hls                rtmps              unix
http               rtmpt
```

Issue resolved!